# why does the texture gets stretched on my rectangle shaped object?

Tags: texturing, uv

I have UV Unwrapped my rectangle looking object.
Even though the UV looks fine to me, the texture gets stretched.

I tried using heavier subdivide to make each face more like a square, I tried different seam patterns but I couldn't find the solution.

I noticed that when I Scale an object, the texture gets stretched, so I created a new squared and extruded it from one side to make a rectangle instead of scaling it to the side, but still same thing happened, texture got streched.

I also tried googling this question, but couldn't find a tutorial talks about unwrapping a rectangle, this might be because it's so easy so no one creates a tutorial about this.
but anyways I finally made the decision to ask myself in here.

How can I fix this?

Below you can find a screenshot of my object, seams and the UV.

[image]

Best regards, 
Amirreza

Comment: Did you apply your scale with Object > Apply > Scale (or CTRL A) before UV unwrapping ? The pattern in the UV editor looks like an unwrapped cube but your object has a soap bar shape

Comment: @Gorgious No man I didn't, I didn't even know about that. thank you for the comment it fixed my issue :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stretching is happening because your model's polygons are rectangular, but the UVs are square. Apply Scale to the object before UV unwrapping.

Comment: Hi. If you need to ask a question to the OP to clarify a detail, this is best done as a comment.

Comment: Oh yeah that fixed the problem, Please edit your answer and add the steps of applying the scale to the object (@Gorgious comment under my question) then I'll accept your answer :)